# indent command does not indent matched lines

Tags: indentation, global-command

I have file where I would like to indent all the lines between curly braces:

```
html {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
font-size: 100%;
font: inherit;
vertical-align: baseline;
}
body {
line-height: 1.5;
color: black;
background: white;
}
```

I could do this with `:g/{/ .+1,/}/-1 >` `Ex` command. However, I also tried to do the same with regular expression `:g/\v\{\_s?\zs\_.{-}\ze\}/ >`. This will match all the lines between curly braces and I expected `>` command to indent the matched lines. Instead, it indents the `html {` and `body {` lines:

```
        html {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
font-size: 100%;
font: inherit;
vertical-align: baseline;
}
        body {
line-height: 1.5;
color: black;
background: white;
}
```

What is the reason for such behavior?

Comment: From vim Documentation `:h global` : `for a multi-line pattern, only the
start of the match matters`; so it only considers just two lines that your matchs start. here the lines include `\zs` exactly after `{`'s and indent them.

Comment: What about `gg=G`?

Comment: @dNitro Actually the `\zs` matches on the line following the '{' since `\_s?` matches a newline. But `:global` marks lines at the start of the entire matching process, even if `\zs` matches on a subsequent line. Unless that's what you meant; I'm not sure :-)

Comment: @Antony, Tanx, crystal clear ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing the problem is that `:global` operates linewise, so the `\zs` and `\ze` in your regex don't do anything; They still apply to the line that matched the *entire pattern*, not the line that the *selection* starts and ends on. For example, if you have the following text:

```
foo
bar
```

and you do

```
:g/foo\n\zsb/d
```

This will delete `foo` rather than deleting `bar`. Keep in mind, this is mostly a guess, I've never ran into this behavior before, all though it's reproducible. Really though, if you think about it, it makes sense. The definition of the global command is:

```
:[range]g[lobal]/{pattern}/[cmd]
            Execute the Ex command [cmd] (default ":p") on the
            LINES within [range] where {pattern} matches.
```

(Emphasis added). `foo` matches the pattern `foo\n\zsbar`, so it's irrelevant that you moved the selection forward; the line still matches. On the other hand, there is no possible way for `bar` to match the pattern `foo\n\zsbar`.

One thing you could do to make your command simpler is to use the negative global command, e.g. an ex command on every line *not* matching. That could just be:

```
:g!/{\|}/>
```